# Spring Data JPA app coonection to Google Cloud Run Postgres

Tags: spring-data-jpa, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run

Google have an [example](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-spring-petclinic-cloudsql) to connect Cloud SQL-MYSQl from [Spring JPA/Boot App](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/tree/9ecdc1111e3da388a750ace41a125287d9620534) ( commit 9ecdc1111e3da388a750ace41a125287d9620534 is used). The example is uses Spring Data and works fine with MySQL. But It does not work when profile is changed to postgress ( after starting right Postgres Database in same account and with same steps in [#2](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-spring-petclinic-cloudsql#2))

```
spring.profiles.active=postgres
```

and replacing

```
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-mysql</artifactId>
with 
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-postgresql</artifactId>
```

and

```
replacing src/main/resources/application-mysql.properties 
with 
 src/main/resources/application-postgres.properties
```

but still applications fails with

> Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class
> path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested
> service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

I could not find any sample.

application-postgres.properties is appended to have

```
spring.profiles.active=postgres
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name= xyzprj:us-central1:postgres-instance
spring.datasource.username=xyzuser
spring.datasource.password=password
```

application-postgres.properties is replaced as followes

```
spring.datasource.username=xyzuser
spring.datasource.password=passord
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.database-name=petclinic
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name=xyzprj:us-central1:postgres-instance
```

later both of these properties files were also changed so that

spring.datasource.username=root

and

spring.datasource.password=root

but same issue
sample is tried on Cloud Shell within Google Cloud,

> gcloud auth application-default login
>
> You are running on a Google Compute Engine virtual machine. The
> service credentials associated with this virtual machine will
> automatically be used by Application Default Credentials, so it is not
> necessary to use this command.
>
> If you decide to proceed anyway, your user credentials may be visible
> to others with access to this virtual machine. Are you sure you want
> to authenticate with your personal account?
>
> Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  n
>
> ERROR: (gcloud.auth.application-default.login) Aborted by user.
>
> ---

Comment: example https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-instance-cloud-run does not use Spring Data JPA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the issue on my side, but I was able to deploy application successfully

Here are the steps I followed

**Step1:** Created `postgresql` using below command

```
gcloud sql instances create postgres-instance \
--database-version=POSTGRES_13 \
 --cpu=1 \
 --memory=4GB \
 --region=us-central \
 --root-password=root
```

**Step2:** Created database using

```
gcloud sql databases create petclinic --instance postgres-instance
```

**Step3:** Connected to the PostgreSQL instance to verify the connection established or not

```
gcloud sql connect postgres-instance
```

**Step4:** replaced the following as you did
In `application.properties`

```
spring.profiles.active=postgres
```

and replacing

```
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-mysql</artifactId>
    with 
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-postgresql</artifactId>
```

and

```
    replacing src/main/resources/application-mysql.properties 
    with 
     src/main/resources/application-postgres.properties
```

**Step5:** In addition to above changes

In `application.properties` replaced

```
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name= POSTGRESQL_CONNECTION_NAME
```

In  `src/main/resources/application-postgres.properties` added

```
spring.datasource.username=USERNAME
spring.datasource.password=PASSWORD
```

In `pom.xml` file added following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgres-socket-factory</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

In `build.grable` file  add

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.cloud.sql:postgres-socket-factory:1.1.0'
}
```

***Note:*** run `gcloud auth application-default login` to access default credential to communicate with`Cloud Sql API`

For clear information check this [document](https://spring-gcp.saturnism.me/app-dev/cloud-services/databases/cloud-sql)

Comment: @puzzled Seems like it is password authentication error. Try running [`gcloud auth application-default login`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/) and can you confirm that you are able to connect `postgresql` by using `gcloud sql connect INSTANCE-NAME` ?

Comment: And Make sure you are passing correct credentials under `src/main/resources/application-postgres.properties`

Comment: it was user error, it works Thanks